# Indexing queries in Railo

Tags: lucene, indexing, railo, cfml, cfindex

I went to the Web Administrator > Services > Search.

I manually create a collection with:

- name "articoli"
- path (a fake one, e.g. /tmp)
- Italian language

Then in my indexer template:

```
<cfquery name="qry">
    SELECT * FROM articoli 
</cfquery>
<cfindex action="update" 
         collection="articoli"
         key="artid"
         type="custom"
         title="artcod"
         query="qry"
         body="artdes" />
```

Result: **collection articoli is undefined**

Any ideas? Other ways for indexing with RAILO+Lucene?

**EDIT:**

I am using Railo 3.3 (old version). Is this kind of indexing available?

Comment: Obviously yes -.- READ THE QUESTION PLEASE!

Comment: Will the cfsearch tag work with collection="articoli"?

Comment: Provide a standalone code example - i.e. use QueryNew to create a dummy query, and run the code outside of your application.

Comment: Also, you haven't specified which version of Railo this is - specifically, is it the latest stable 4.0.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking [the Railo source for v3.3](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/3.3/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/search/SearchEngineSupport.java) indicates that **the error "collection articoli is undefined" will occur if the collection named doesn't exist** - a simple search reveals only [one instance](https://github.com/getrailo/railo/blob/master/railo-java/railo-core/src/railo/runtime/search/SearchEngineSupport.java#L83) of a "collection X is undefined" error message).

This suggests that either **the name does not match** what you typed into the web administrator, or that you created the articoli collection in **a different web administrator** to where you are running the code.